# How to mock ajax request in Grails unit test

Tags: grails, spock

I have a controller action, which handles both ajax and non-ajax request. But, if its an ajax request, it does some extra stuff.

> if( request.xhr ) { Do stuff only for ajax request  }

But, when i tried to have unit test for this. No matter what i did, i was not able to create/mock a ajax request. ie, request.xhr fails all the time.

I did tried

> request.makeAjaxRequest()

But, it doesnt work. Any idea ??

Comment: Show the code of the unit test that you wrote.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this? I am having the same sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your unit test you can do something like this:

```
request.makeAjaxRequest()
```

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/f164ed3743378fb9e00d75deca15935283fc7157/grails-test/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/testing/GrailsMockHttpServletRequest.groovy#L179-L186

Answer (score 1):

Although it's been a very long time, since the question is asked but here's my solution for Grails upcoming newbie's...

```
controller.metaClass.getRequest = { ->
        [xhr: true]
}
```

or simply it could be

```
void 'test list'() {
    when:
    request.method = 'POST'
    request.makeAjaxRequest()
    controller.getPage()

    then:
    // …
}
```

This solution worked for my case of mocking **Ajax Request**

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following header to request: `controller.request.addHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')`

Comment: FYI... We provide a convenience method for doing that.  `request.makeAjaxRequest()` as I mentioned in a separate answer.